# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. yet foreach loop is working

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

so im having a weird problem. when i make a linq query on a datatable I get

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

but when a use forloop on the result it works correctly.dt is a datatable

```
var productdata = from data in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                  where data.Field<string>("Edited").ToString().ToUpper() == "NEW"
                  select data;//I get the object reference error here

foreach (var item in productdata) //but here the control goes inside the foreachloop even though the object refrence was null and the code gets executed correctly
{
   //operation
}
```

only after the last iteraton does it give the null reference exception again. I dont understand why this is happening

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/447156)

Comment: i want to know why is the forrloop getting executed correctly

Comment: ok i figured that much then why does it give a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error after the last iteration

Comment: convert your linq into another foreach loop and debug all steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The items in `productdata` are produced lazily, and the exception probably occurs in the `Where` clause:

```
where data.Field<string>("Edited").ToString().ToUpper() == "NEW"
```

the `productdata` sequence is not null so the foreach can begin executing, but the exception will not be thrown until `MoveNext` is called and the `Edited` field is accessed and found to be null.

Answer (score 1):

Update your linq query as follows:

```
var productdata = (from data in dt
                  where data.Field<string>("Edited").ToString().ToUpper() == "NEW"
                  select data)
                  .ToList();//I get the object reference error here
```

This will return the results set immediately, and validate the foreach loop.

Comment: when i do tolist im instantly getting exception  "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Mysterio11 why youre converting it into var , try getting it in datarow by using dt.select();

Comment: @Mysterio11 I would suggest checking that 'dt' (assuming thats your dbContext.dt) is not null before attempting to build the linq query.

Answer (score 1):

Why use of linQ here 
where you can simply get your output by using

```
 var productdata = dt.Select("Edited='NEW'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. you see i was creating this datatable by reading an excel file. and in the file only one row had "NEW" in the edited column. the rest were empty. As soon as i put dummy values in the rest of the rows it started working perfectly. Donno why this is happening but at least got my code to work